# Sitecore search hits are null

Tags: solr, sitecore

I am running the below code

```
IQueryable<customSearchResultItem> query = context.GetQueryable<customSearchResultItem>().Where(CombinPredicates);
var hits = query.GetResults().Hits;

Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("search query hits:" + hits.Count(), context.Index);
foreach (var item in hits)
{
     string builder = string.Empty;
     try
     {
        string docitemid = item.Document.ItemId.ToString();
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("document itemid:" + docitemid, item);

        Item resultItem = item.Document.GetItem();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("search error going through hits:" + ex.Message, ex);
         builder += item.Document.ItemId.ToString() + "\n";
         continue;
     }
}
```

the above actually returns results in the "hits" variable. However, I was getting zero results rendered out to the front end of the site. the code above is my debugging code to see what is going on.

With the hits I get back, I just loop through, nothing more.
When performing the  loop and writing to logs, the below 2 lines actually return as expected, a valid Sitecore itemID

```
string docitemid = item.Document.ItemId.ToString();
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("document itemid:" + docitemid, item);
```

However, the following line

```
 Item resultItem = item.Document.GetItem();
```

returns as NULL

why would this be?

to complicate further, this code actual works in a one environment but not another, hence the reason for the debugging.
Also, the Sitecore item is present it both master and web databases and in the SOLR index

Comment: Could you post your customSearchResultItem class?

Comment: Try to fetch the item via Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(docitemid)

Comment: Item contextdatabaseItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(docitemid); 

this returns "object reference"

I have also checked the context database:
string contextdbname = Sitecore.Context.Database.Name;

this returns WEB

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem where I was searching in the Prod (web) environment items indexed via the Stage Sitecore instance. I believe the GetItem() method uses the *database*, *item id*, *language* and *version* of the *search result item*, which are parsed from the *_uniqueid* that looks something like this:

```
...
 "_uniqueid":"sitecore://stage/{d31b5802-c123-4690-86ff-8566dc896814}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=my_site_index"
...
```

So in my case it wasn't finding the Sitecore item, because it was looking in the **stage** database, where as my Sitecore.Context.Database was the **web** one.

I know this answer is way late :-), but I hope it helps someone else who happens to run into this issue.